# Vue.js change background-image on multiple conditions

Tags: css, vue.js, conditional-statements, styles

is there a way to change a background-image on conditions?

Im trying to build a weatherapp and I will change the background of a div.
Like:

Weather api returns:

1. rainy -> change background image to rain.jpg
2. snow -> change background image to snow.jpg
3. sunny -> change background to sunny.jpg
4. etc.

I've tried multiple ways already but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template>
  <div :class="{background_image}"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // ...
  data() {
    return {
        backgroundImage: 'snow'
    },
   computed:{
    background_image : function () {

        switch(this.backgroundImage) {
            case 'snow':
                    return 'bg-snow';
            case 'rainy':
                    return 'bg-rainy';
            case 'sunny':
                    return 'bg-sunny';
            default:
                    return 'bg-default';
            }       
    }
  },
  methods: {
    apiCall() {
        //api call update background image according to the response
        this.backgroundImage = response ; // response contains sunny text
        
    }
  },
  // ...
}
</script>
<style>

.bg-sunny{
    background-image: url('sunny.jpg'); 
}

.bg-snow{
    background-image: url('snow.jpg'); 
}
.bg-rainy{
    background-image: url('rainy.jpg'); 
}
.bg-default{
    background-image: url('default.jpg'); 
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior by looking up the image in an object, where you have defined your key and the corresponding image value. In addition, you need to tell webpack to require that media file. That `require` tells webpack to treat this file as a request.

```
<template>
  <div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${weatherTypes[getWeatherType()]})` }"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // ...
  data() {
    return {
      weatherTypes: {
        snow: require('some/path/snow.png'),
        sun: require('some/path/sun.png'),
        // ...
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getWeatherType() { return 'snow'; },
  },
  // ...
}
</script>
```

[Reproduction link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-js-dynamic-image-path-gpdw7)

Comment: Thank you.

It is working but the background-image is not showing up.

Comment: I've updated my answer to a more modern one. Basically you need to tell webpack with require to import the image.

Comment: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Comment: Sorry, the issue was that Webpack cannot really import dynamic content. I've made some minor changes. In addition, I've added a small reproduction link.